# Group direct sum construction. Problem from Undergraduate Algebra by Serge Lang.

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, abelian-groups, direct-sum

I have been reading on *Undergraduate Algebra* by Serge Lang, and not so far deep in I got myself stuck already.

The problem says:

> If $A$ is an abelian group, written additively, and $n$ is a positive integer such that $\forall x\in A$ it holds $nx=0$. Assume that we can write $n=rs$ where $r$ and $s$ are positive relatively prime integers. Let $A_r$ consist of all $x\in A$ such that $rx=0$, and similarly $A_s$ of all $x \in A$ such that $sx=0$. Show that $A$ is direct sum of $A_s$ and $A_r$.

I have tried the following :

If $nx=0$ and $x \neq 0$ then $nx=(rs)x=0$. Then it holds that either $rx=0$ or $sx=0$ or both.

Now I claim that for nonzero $x$, both can not be true at the same time, thus making $A_r$ and $A_s$ mutually disjoint. If both held at the same time then $rx=sx$ then it holds that $(r-s)x=0$ then since $x$ is nonzero it must hold that $r=s$. Thus since they are relatively prime they must be equal to 1, thus group would be trivial thus x would have to be zero, which is contradiction.
Thus the 2 defined sets must be disjoint if the group is nontrivial.

Now since $r$ and $s$ are relatively prime there are $p$ and $m$ such that $pr+ms=1$.

Now I claim that every element in group $A$ can be written as sum of elements of $A_r$ and $A_s$. Since:
$$a=1a=(pr+ms)a=pra+msa.$$

But from above arguments it is obvious that each elements of $A$ must belong to either $A_r$ or $A_s$.

What is unclear to me is whether my proof is correct or not. Especially the part where I prove that every element is a sum of elements of subsets seems really sketchy to me.

This problem is to be found in the book *Undergraduate Algebra* by Serge Lang, third edition, on page 40, problem 15.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is mostly correct; however, there are some (important!) details that should be corrected.

We need to establish two facts: $A_r \cap A_s = \{0\}$ and $A = A_r + A_s$.

The second part, where you prove that every element of $A$ is a sum of elements from $A_r$ and $A_s$ is clear. You show that $$a = pra + msa,$$
and it is obvious that $pra \in A_s$, while $msa \in A_r$. This shows that $A = A_r + A_s$.

The bit that needs correcting is the first part of the proof, where you show that $A_r \cap A_s = \{0\}$. (Notice, they are *not* disjoint, as they share a common element - $0$. It is more precise to say their intersection is trivial).

In a general Abelian group setting, the fact that $(r-s)x = 0$ **does not** imply that $(r-s) = 0$.
A way around this problem is to use $pr + ms = 1$ again: if $x \in A_r \cap A_s$, we have:
$$x = 1x = prx + ms x = 0 + 0 = 0.$$

This shows that $A_r \cap A_s = \{0\}$, as desired.

Apart from that, the proof is ok. There is just one (common) mistake that you should be careful about. You claim the following:

"If $nx=0$ and $x\neq0$ $then nx=(rs)x=0$. Then it holds that either $rx=0$ or $sx=0$ or both."

Actually, this isn't true; we can have $rx \neq 0$ and $sx \neq 0$ but still $rsx = 0$ (try to think of an example). Fortunately, we don't even need this conclusion to complete our proof.

Comment: This is one of the most educational answers I have obtained on this site.Thank you very much for your guidance.

Comment: @TheCoolDrop great, it's very nice to hear that. No problem :)